# Are python generators faster than nested for loops?

Tags: python, cprofile

I having some problems trying to understand generators.

Do these function's execution time differ when doing the same task?

```
def slow_sum(size):
    x= 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            x += i + j
    return x

def fast_sum(size):
    return sum( [ (i+j) for j in range(size) for i in range(size)] )

size = 2000
slow_val = slow_sum(size)
fast_val = fast_sum(size)
assert slow_val == fast_val, "Values are not equal"
```

When profiling both functions on my computer using cProfile I got these result, but I expected them to be similar.

### Total Time

- slow_sum(2000)

  - 0.85 ms
- fast_sum(2000)

  - 0.05 ms

Original File: https://pastebin.com/fDfaSqyZ

My Output: https://pastebin.com/wyy3v3iy

Comment: That's not a generator, that's a list comprehension. With a generator, it would be  `sum((i+j) for j in range(size) for i in range(size))`

Comment: Don't be deceived. It is not faster. See this reverse question to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905965/python-why-is-list-comprehension-slower-than-for-loop

Comment: @Tomothy32, generators are generally not faster than creating a list first. For example, see `str.join`; try it with a generator vs a list and compare the results

Comment: it's special for `str.join` because it needs a list anyway and if it doesn't have one, it builds one. Not the case for `sum`

Comment: `slow_sum` has to execute individual Python add operations; `fast_sum` sums the list in C.

Comment: slow_sum is faster on my system :) both are computed in around 0.5 second. I'm beginning to doubt about your benchmark

Comment: I got almost the same speed: `size = 1000`, 10 times with `timeit`: `fast 1.25320039 - slow 1.1005855780000002`

Comment: This is a leading question because now we have to reconcile whether the statement that "generators are faster than for-loops", is true; then we have to come up with an explanation as to why. But what if you are wrong? And as most of the comments have indicated, your initial statement is actually not true; also it is not a generator expression. The question you should be asking is why in THIS case; the generator expression was faster than the for-loop.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right part of the profiler output? You should be looking at cumtime or the percall column to the right of cumtime. tottime ignores time spent in `sum` or in the list comprehension's stack frame.

Comment: Okay, yep, you're looking at tottime.

Comment: Oh welp, my bad :/ @user2357112

Comment: Generators save space. Space is sometimes more important than time complexity in terms of actual resources, and therefore real time. I am addressing the hypothetical, and ignoring the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong column of the profiler output. `tottime` doesn't count all the time `fast_sum` spends inside the `sum` call or the list comprehension's stack frame. You should be looking at `cumtime`, which is near equal for the two functions.